# Trying to stop regex at a tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I know there are other posts with a similar name but I've looked through them and they haven't helped me resolve this.

I'm trying to get my head around regex and preg_match.  I am going through a body of text and each time a link exists I want it to be extracted.  I'm currently using the following:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
```

which works fine until it finds one that has `<br` after it.  Then I get the url plus the `<br` which means it doesn't work correctly.  How can I have it so that it stops at the `<` without including it?

Also, I have been looking everywhere for a clear explanation of using regex and I'm still confused by it.  Has anyone any good guides on it for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\S*` is too broad. In particular, I could inject into your code with a URL like:

```
http://hax.hax/"><script>alert('HAAAAAAAX!');</script>
```

You should only allow characters that are allowed in URLs:

```
[-A-Za-z0-9._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=]*
```

Some of these characters are only allowed in specific places (such as `?`) so if you want better validation you will need [more cleverness](http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the)

Comment: You are a frickin star.  Not just for solving the issue but warning me about this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\S` exclude the open tag char from the class:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/[^<]*)?/";
```

You might even want to be more restrictive by only allowing characters valid in URLs:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/[a-zA-Z_\-\.%\?&]*)?/";
```

(or some more characters)

Comment: BAAAAAAD! Bad bad bad! Now your regex accepts "urls" with anything in them, like *new lines*...

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: This is not perfect, but it solves the specific problem in the question. Made it more specific, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one as presented on the:
http://regex101.com/r/zV1uI7

On the bottom of the site you got it explained step by step.